# Global variable value update at task level in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a requirement of doing some integer variable updates based on some computations in my transformations . For eg if I get some discrepancy in record matching then I want to increment a value and use it then and there .

I have explored the use of accumulators,

> but its value can only be used in driver

which will be very tedious for me as I am dealing with billions of rows.
Please suggest me a possible solution for global variable updates in spark like COUNTERS in MapReduce framework.

Answer (score 0):

Accumulators is the best alternative of counters in spark.but have to use in action  instead of transformation as computations inside transformations are evaluated lazily.you can find example in below link.

https://github.com/prithvirajbose/spark-dev/blob/master/src/main/scala/examples/PurchaseLogAnalysis.scala

I faced the same problem.Using Accumulators is a good practice for this use case and it wont affect the spark performance and safer to use.

Comment: I understand the use of accumulators .. but I have multiple counters to be set and that too for billions of rows . I can't perform this in an action .

Comment: you can try this ,I guess will help you.Create an scala object in which you define the private variable that you want to increase .example :object Counters{
    private var counter_bad_record= 0
    private def inc_Counter = {counter_bad_record+= 1; counter_bad_record}
} and call the function in your transformation like  "Counters.inc_Counter" according to your conditions.

Comment: in java its like creating a function which have static variable.import that class to your spark application and call that function which increase the static variable, as static variable get initialized once.